# Establishing the name associated with a HTML link

Tags: python, html, http, python-3.x

I wish to download the files associated with a set of links in a html document.

A link might appear like this:

```
<a href="d?kjdfer87">
```

But when I click on it in my browser, I get the following file downloaded:

```
file2.txt
```

The following will download the file via python:

```
opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
r = opener.open("unknown.txt")
r.read()
```

but how do I establish that the file was actually called file2.txt?

Answer (score 2):

Check the `Content-Disposition` header on the response. It can suggest a filename. I believe this would be in `r.info().dict['Content-Disposition']`.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually this simple:

```
r.info().get_filename()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you think you need the name. You should call it in exactly the same way as the browser does, ie with the value in the href.

Comment: The browser has a different name to the one in the href

Answer (score 0):

The `Content-Disposition` header in the HTTP response is what specified that the response should be downloaded with a specific filename.

See: 
[How to encode the filename parameter of Content-Disposition header in HTTP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93551/how-to-encode-the-filename-parameter-of-content-disposition-header-in-http)